# npm install hangs in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, npm-install

I am trying to start my react docker container (https://github.com/AndrewRPorter/flask-react-nginx) but the install hangs after spitting out various warnings.

I am running on Ubuntu. My intuition is some kind of network interference. I am not using a VPN.

My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install 2>&1

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

# start the development server
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The output I get on install is:

```
npm WARN tarball tarball data for react-dom@16.13.1 (sha512-81PIMmVLnCNLO/fFOQxdQkvEq/+Hfpv24XNJfpyZhTRfO0QcmQIF/PgCa1zCOj2w1hrn12MFLyaJ/G0+Mxtfag==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @testing-library/react@9.5.0 (sha512-di1b+D0p+rfeboHO5W7gTVeZDIK5+maEgstrZbWZSSvxDyfDRkkyBE1AJR5Psd6doNldluXlCWqXriUfqu/9Qg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for pretty-format@24.9.0 (sha512-00ZMZUiHaJrNfk33guavqgvfJS30sLYf0f8+Srklv0AMPodGGHcoHgksZ3OThYnIvOd+8yMCn0YiEOogjlgsnA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for lodash@4.17.15 (sha512-8xOcRHvCjnocdS5cpwXQXVzmmh5e5+saE2QGoeQmbKmRS6J3VQppPOIt0MnmE+4xlZoumy0GPG0D0MVIQbNA1A==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.25.0 (sha512-W2YyMtjmlrOjtXc+FtTelVs9OhuR6OlYc4XKIslJ8PUJOqgYYAPRJhAqkYRQo3G4sjvG8jSodsNycEn4W2gHUw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for webpack@4.42.0 (sha512-EzJRHvwQyBiYrYqhyjW9AqM90dE4+s1/XtCfn7uWg6cS72zH+2VPFAlsnW0+W0cDi0XRjNKUMoJtpSi50+Ph6w==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @testing-library/user-event@7.2.1 (sha512-oZ0Ib5I4Z2pUEcoo95cT1cr6slco9WY7yiPpG+RGNkj8YcYgJnM7pXmYmorNOReh8MIGcKSqXyeGjxnr8YiZbA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for eslint@6.8.0 (sha512-K+Iayyo2LtyYhDSYwz5D5QdWw0hCacNzyq1Y821Xna2xSJj7cijoLLYmLxTQgcgZ9mC61nryMy9S7GRbYpI5Ig==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@6.2.3 (sha512-CawzfGt9w83tyuVekn0GDPU9ytYtxyxyFZ3aSWROmnRRFQFT2BiPJd7jvRdzNDi6oLWaS2asMeYSNMjWTV4eNg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for source-map@0.6.1 (sha512-UjgapumWlbMhkBgzT7Ykc5YXUT46F0iKu8SGXq0bcwP5dz/h0Plj6enJqjz1Zbq2l5WaqYnrVbwWOWMyF3F47g==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for webpack-dev-server@3.10.3 (sha512-e4nWev8YzEVNdOMcNzNeCN947sWJNd43E5XvsJzbAL08kGc2frm1tQ32hTJslRS+H65LCb/AaUCYU7fjHCpDeQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for postcss@7.0.27 (sha512-WuQETPMcW9Uf1/22HWUWP9lgsIC+KEHg2kozMflKjbeUtw9ujvFX6QmIfozaErDkmLWS9WEnEdEe6Uo9/BNTdQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for core-js@3.6.4 (sha512-4paDGScNgZP2IXXilaffL9X7968RuvwlkK3xWtZRVqgd8SYNiVKRJvkFd1aqqEuPfN7E68ZHEp9hDj6lHj4Hyw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for source-map@0.6.1 (sha512-UjgapumWlbMhkBgzT7Ykc5YXUT46F0iKu8SGXq0bcwP5dz/h0Plj6enJqjz1Zbq2l5WaqYnrVbwWOWMyF3F47g==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for postcss@7.0.21 (sha512-uIFtJElxJo29QC753JzhidoAhvp/e/Exezkdhfmt8AymWT6/5B7W1WmponYWkHk2eg6sONyTch0A3nkMPun3SQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for jsdom@14.1.0 (sha512-O901mfJSuTdwU2w3Sn+74T+RnDVP+FuV5fH8tcPWyqrseRAb0s5xOtPgCFiPOtLcyK7CLIJwPyD83ZqQWvA5ng==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @testing-library/react@9.5.0 (sha512-di1b+D0p+rfeboHO5W7gTVeZDIK5+maEgstrZbWZSSvxDyfDRkkyBE1AJR5Psd6doNldluXlCWqXriUfqu/9Qg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for react-dom@16.13.1 (sha512-81PIMmVLnCNLO/fFOQxdQkvEq/+Hfpv24XNJfpyZhTRfO0QcmQIF/PgCa1zCOj2w1hrn12MFLyaJ/G0+Mxtfag==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting @testing-library/react@9.5.0:
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting @testing-library/react@9.5.0:
npm ERR! sha512-di1b+D0p+rfeboHO5W7gTVeZDIK5+maEgstrZbWZSSvxDyfDRkkyBE1AJR5Psd6doNldluXlCWqXriUfqu/9Qg== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-di1b+D0p+rfeboHO5W7gTVeZDIK5+maEgstrZbWZSSvxDyfDRkkyBE1AJR5Psd6doNldluXlCWqXriUfqu/9Qg== but got sha512-Bf+V8vCdAtDbh2K4IVqKgtvkHNi23ZwxU3mYrjvvZtbgOEeMSTVwEo77cPeZBcGWnKUM8XDQjnHfy3ebg/ugKA==. (64745 bytes)
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @babel/types@7.9.0 (sha512-BS9JKfXkzzJl8RluW4JGknzpiUV7ZrvTayM6yfqLTVBEnFtyowVIOu6rqxRd5cVO6yGoWf4T8u8dgK9oB+GCng==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @babel/parser@7.9.4 (sha512-bC49otXX6N0/VYhgOMh4gnP26E9xnDZK3TmbNpxYzzz9BQLBosQwfyOe9/cXUU3txYhTzLCbcqd5c8y/OmCjHA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
...
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/app/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/hacks/flex-wrap.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/app/node_modules/core-js/internals/array-buffer-native.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/app/node_modules/core-js/internals/array-buffer-view-core.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/app/node_modules/core-js/internals/array-buffer.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/usr/app/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/asserts/generated'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/app/node_modules/lodash/fp/_convertBrowser.js'
```

Comment: This comment (https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20925#issuecomment-398615344) says that his issue was a proxy issue. Would this be a docker proxy issue?

Answer (score 9):

Using a different image solved the issue for me.
Try using a lighter images as given below.

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine
```

Answer (score 7):

when want to execute docker run add new flag to it , network

```
docker run -t yourdockerhub/package --network=host .
```

it take 2 centuries of me to find out , i guess it also work for you if it hang on npm install .

Comment: You save a life here brother, thank you! I would never have figured this out!

Answer (score 1):

Even if it should not make any difference, for me adding `--verbose` to the `npm install` command in the Dockerfile fixed the problem.

```
RUN npm install --verbose
```

Edit:
Adding `--verbose` helps some times, but not always. Pulling the images before running can also help.

```
docker pull
docker run
# or
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in my UI container.

Try removing node_modules from your /usr/src/app folder in the container and try again.

If you still face the issue then remove UI container and Image by below commands.

```
Docker rmi IMAGE_ID
Docker rm CONTAINER_ID
```

Then try again.